# What are 'c' and 'value' ? Can someone explain how these works?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**First example:**

```
my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'pear']

for c, value in enumerate(my_list, 1):
    print(c, value)
```

**Another example:**

```
[print(int(x)==sum(int(d)**p for p,d in enumerate(x,1)))for x in[input()]]
```

How does `x`, `d`, and `p` work ?

Comment: Please limit your posts to a single question

Answer (score 1):

So, there are two small questions here:

**a)**

```
my_list = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'pear']

for c, value in enumerate(my_list, 1):
    print(c, value)
```

Step as follows:

1. `enumerate(my_list, 1)` will get a list with index, here the output is a enumereate object, if use `list(enumerate(my_list, 1)` to have a look, it is `[(1, 'apple'), (2, 'banana'), (3, 'grapes'), (4, 'pear')]`.
2. So, with every `for`, the first iterate get `c=1, value='apple'`, the second get `c=2, value='banana'` ...
3. Then the final output is:

```
1 apple
2 banana 
3 grapes 
4 pear
```

**b)**

```
[print(int(x)==sum(int(d)**p for p,d in enumerate(x,1)))for x in[input()]]
```

Step as follows:

1. First, it's a [list comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/), I suppose you have known that.
2. The `input` first expect a user input, let's input `100` for example, then the `input` will treat it as a `str`, so `[input()]` returns `['100']`
3. Then with `for x in [input()]` the `x` is `'100'`
4. Next according `list comprehension`, it will handle `int(x)==sum(int(d)**p for p,d in enumerate(x,1))`
5. `(int(d)**p for p,d in enumerate(x,1))` will first iterate '100', get something like `[(1, '1'), (2, '0'), (3, '0')]` if use list to see it, just similar as example 1. Then calculate `int(d)**p` for every iterate and finally use `sum` to get the result, similar to `int('1')**1 + int('0')**2 + int('0')**3`, the result is `1`.
6. So `print(int('100')==1` certainly output `False`
7. And the return value of `print` function call is always `None`, so `list comprehension` will make the new list is `[None]`.
8. So the final outout is (NOTE: 100 is the echo of your input):

```
>>> [print(int(x)==sum(int(d)**p for p,d in enumerate(x,1)))for x in[input()]]
100
False
[None]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to look up things in the Python documentation when you have questions about built in functions like `enumerate`. A link to that is [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

To explain it, enumerate will help you iterate over all values in a list, and if you pass in an optional parameter number (like the 1 in your example), it specifies the starting index to iterate from.

What enumerate returns is first the index and then the item stored at that index in the list. So `c` in your example is going to be each index (1, 2, 3, etc) as it loops through the for loop. And `value` in your example is the actual value stored at that index in the list.

Also remember that lists start at index 0 instead of 1 as their first value.

Answer (score 0):

The common naming system when using *enumerate* is **idx, item** it makes it clear what each element represents and would suit you best to follow this naming scheme

```
l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print([(idx, item) for idx, item in enumerate(l)])
```

> ```
> [(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
> ```

As you can see **idx** represents the index of the item, and **item** is the item.